# JBPM AND MYSQL INTEGRATION STEP BY STEP

Tags: mysql, integration, jbpm

***Hi All,
 would you please tell me how to integrate JBPM with mysql database.
 please tell me step by step because I am very beginner in JBPM.***

Thanks in advance
Dal Singar Yadav

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this:
[Set up jBPM 5.4 Final Installer to use MySQL](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpJBPM54FinalInstallerToUseMySQL-OrHowToRunSection37OfTheUserGuide#Set_up_MySQL)

if you are new to jbpm, i highly recommend being active in jboss community. That helps a lot.